# Event Management plugin

Tags: events, calendar, plugin-shopp

I am working on a site that has the option of using
Event Expresso
Event Manager Pro

The events part of the site is quite complicated, and needs to have
- a calendar
- a registration page
- 'buy tickets' functionality with both Paypal and http://www.authorize.net/ 
-  email confirmations

I haven't worked a lot with event plugins, can anyone recommend one of the above plugins over the other?

It sounds like there might be quite a lot of customization required, so I guess part of this question is, "Which is the easiest to customize?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this does not meet your requirement of supporting Paypal and Authorize.net, but it does support Eventbrite, so it may be worth looking into:

[The Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/)

Answer (score 0):

or http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager-extended/
good support via forum and many possibilities